# AG_E_PARSER_BAD_PROPERTY_VALUE [Line: 7 Position: 121] error

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Im getting this error but I cant see anything wrong with my xaml. I treble checked it. Any ideas?

```
    <controls:PanoramaItem Header="first item">
        <!--Double line list with text wrapping-->
        <ListBox Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="450">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Url}" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="1" MouseEnter="Image_MouseEnter"></Image>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="2" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </controls:PanoramaItem>
```

Comment: Are you sure `MouseEnter="Image_MouseEnter"` event exists in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure `MouseEnter="Image_MouseEnter"` event exists in your code?  Most of the times this error occurs due to unavailability/inaccessibility of handler in the code behind

Answer (score 0):

Found it, Image_MouseEnter was set to private not public. The parser error was pointing me at the wrong direction :) Thanks  Haris Hasan